# setting javascript variable value in JSP:UseBean using Set property

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jsf, jstl

I am new to Java and don't know whether it's possible or not:

How to populate the variable of JSP:bean with already existing JavaScript variables present in the JavaScript?

Comment: Demonstrating the situation with appropriate code example(s) would be more helpful to you.

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696722/how-to-pass-javascript-values-to-jsf-el-and-backing-bean.

Answer (score 0):

You have to post the value of the js variable to server side and then set the value to the desired java bean.

Comment: can u please tell me how to do that , that will be vary helpfull.

Comment: Several ways you can do it, but in general, as Paraksh K said, you need to send a GET or POST request and add the js value in the URL as a query string, such as yourServlet?jsVarName=xxx and then parse the value of query string in your servlet and set it to the java bean. For POST request, you can post the value in the body instead of URL. You can use AJAX to get a user-friendly interaction.

Answer (score 0):

First of all **JSP** is nothing but a servlet running on the Server to generate html pages and **Javascript** is a client-side scripting language, so as such there is no direct interaction between the two.

But if you want to set some variable from javascript in a JSP, then you would have to send that variable value to the server either by a GET or POST request or using Ajax requests.

I would suggest going through tutorials which explain the concepts of JSPs, we have a good [wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info) for JSP with some very useful links as well.