# how to call jsf managed bean inside jquery file

Tags: jquery, jsf

i have a jquery file that have comfirm dialog if user chose yes i need to call method from jsf

thats where i need to call jsf managed bean in jquery :

```
 jConfirm('item '+ui.item.context.id+'you want continu ?', 'alerte', function(r) {     
                  if(r)          
                  {
              // i want to call the addmember methode here
             addmember(ui.sender.attr('id'));// i need the right way to call it this is wrong way
                   }
                    else
                    {
                    $(ui.sender).sortable('cancel'); // refuse element to be dropped
                    }
```

and in the jsf managed bean "Managedbeanmembers" i have :

```
void addmember(String name)
{
  listmembers.add(name);
}
```

**Edit 1:**

i wil try this time to be more clear to explain to you what i need :

i have a method in jsf managed bean that get the value and insert in the database :

```
    public void exec() {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    Map map = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
    String name1 = (String) map.get("name1");
    String name2 = (String) map.get("name2");

    manageTesttable.persist(name1);   
}
```

in Jsf i include it with :

```
 <p:remoteCommand name="remoteCommandFunctionName"   
                  actionListener="#{gestionduplanning.exec()}"/>
```

and in my Javascript file :

```
jConfirm('item '+ui.item.context.id+' capacite Cuisson epuise vous voulez continue comme meme ?', 'alerte', function(r) {     
                  if(r)          
                  { 

                  remoteCommandFunctionName({name1:'value1', name2:'value2'});

                   }
                    else
                    {
                    $(ui.sender).sortable('cancel'); // refuse element to be dropped
                    }
```

but when i insert i have null value why name1 and name2 are null ??

Comment: Create a `commandButton` with a CSS that makes it invisible (I think it is `visibility:none` and just "click" it.

Comment: can you give me an example ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to invoke a JSF managed bean on a HTML DOM event using native JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588327/how-to-invoke-a-jsf-managed-bean-on-a-html-dom-event-using-native-javascript)

Comment: @BalusC i edited my post to explain more

Comment: i tryed also the solution of              var input = document.getElementById('formid:inputid');
                    input.value = 'newvalue';  and in the jsf file <input type="text" id="formid:inputid" value="#{gestionduplanning.testvalue}" />  but not working i have empty value for this methode

Comment: for the example with <input the value is showen in the jsf page but when i get it in the jsf managed bean i have empty value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility - create a hidden button and click it like @SJuan76 suggested - [here's](http://liferay-blogging.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-to-trigger-icefaces-jsf-action-by.html) an example.

Another possibility - if you are using richfaces try the `jsFunction` - see [here](http://mkblog.exadel.com/2010/06/using-richfaces-a4jjsfunction-sending-an-ajax-request-from-any-javascript/).

Edit: In case of Primefaces - there is `p:remoteCommand` providing a similar functionality.

Comment: i need to add argument in my function in jquery before send it to the server how i can do that ??

Comment: Are you using richfaces or not?

Comment: In this case you can use `p:remoteCommand` to simplify thigs. A similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7497750/how-do-you-pass-parametersfrom-javascript-into-remotecommand-then-send-it-to) showing how to pass parameters.

Comment: i followed the example and i can call the function inside the managed bean but the problem i can get the value of parametres passed :remoteCommandFunctionName({name1:'value1', name2:'value2'}); when i try to get them with     FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    Map map = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
    String name1 = (String) map.get("name1");
    String name2 = (String) map.get("name2"); i have nothing

Comment: Try `remoteCommandFunctionName([{name1:'value1', name2:'value2'}]); `

Comment: You probably use an old primefaces version - in such case pass the [parameter using an `<input` tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696722/how-to-pass-javascript-values-to-jsf-el-and-backing-bean). Just set the value before calling `remoteCommandFunctionName()` and the rest should work.

Comment: and how we can get in Javascript the value returned by method called in javascript ?

Comment: Directly you can't as the call is asynchronous. You can however use a callback function passed to the  `oncomplete` attribute of `p:remoteCommand`